# Subtracting two timestamps and round the result up to the nearest minute and convert to an integer

Tags: oracle

I'm attempting to write a Sql Statement in Oracle that subtracts two Timestamp fields.  The result of the subtraction returns a value such as +00 00:22:09.000000 which is 22 minutes and 9 seconds.  How would I round the result up to 23 minutes?  I want the final value to return just 23 (an integer basically). The way I'm subtracting the two timestamps is (timestamp_1 - timestamp_2).

Answer (score 0):

Something like extract(minute from (timestamp_1 - timestamp_2 + 1/(24*60)) should do

Comment: Thank you for the response.  My simplified scenario was pretty close to reality but in actuality my need was a little more complicated.  Your suggestion helped me change my approach and I was able to produce what I needed so thank you for the nudge in the right direction.